# embedded Pig Script using Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-pig

I'm trying to run a Pig Script thats imbedded in python. I've done
this without issue on my own machine running the script like pig-x
local pigRunner.py
but when I moved it over to Amazon's EC2 I got a surprising error:

```
File "pigRunner.py", line 3 in <module>
  from org.apache.pig.scripting import *
ImportError: No module named pig

[1]+ Exit 6 pig -x mapreduce pigRunner.py
```

Has anyone else had trouble running Python scripts over at Amazon? Is
there something special I should do in order to get them to process?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This issue may help you to get further: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2665

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and found it was a path issue. I am running on AMI version '2.4.2 (Hadoop 1.0.3) - latest'.

In my embedded pig python file I had to add the following location to the python path before importing anything from pig:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sys.path.append('/home/hadoop/.versions/pig-0.11.1.1/lib/pig/pig-0.11.1.1-amzn.jar/Lib')
from org.apache.pig.scripting import *
```

Then the jython interpreter was able to find all the necessary pig modules.